# Parse Error: Syntax Error unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW expection ')'

Tags: php, html

here's the error I keep getting:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW, expecting ')' in .../Themes/default/Display.template.php on line 170

Here's the code:

```
'notify' => array(
    'test' => 'can_mark_notify', 
    'text' => 125, 
    'image' => 'notify.gif', 
    'lang' => true, 
    'custom' => 
        'onclick="return confirm(Â¥'' 
        . (
            $context['is_marked_notify'] 
            ? $txt['notification_disable_topic'] 
            : $txt['notification_enable_topic']
        ) 
        . 'Â¥');"',
    'url' => $scripturl 
        . '?action=notify;sa=' 
        . ($context['is_marked_notify'] ? 'off' : 'on') 
        . '; topic=' . $context['current_topic'] 
        . '.' . $context['start'] 
        . '; sesc=' 
        . $context['session_id']),
```

I've checked to see if all of the parentheses are closed and they seem to be. I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got unbalanced single quotes starting at the `'custom => 'onclick=...` where you insert some PHP array variables into the javascript.

```
'notify' => array(
    'test' => 'can_mark_notify',
    'text' => 125,
    'image' => 'notify.gif',
    'lang' => true,
    'custom' => 'onclick="return confirm(Â¥'' . ($context['is_marked_notify'] ? 
                                         ^^^^^ right here
          $txt['notification_disable_topic'] : $txt['notification_enable_topic']) . 'Â¥');"',
    'url' => $scripturl . '?action=notify;sa=' . ($context['is_marked_notify'] ? 'off' : 'on') . ';topic=' . $context['current_topic'] . '.' . $context['start'] . ';sesc=' . $context['session_id']),
```

As well, you should be very careful inserting what appears to be text into those onclick handlers. What if `$txt['notification_disable_topic']` and the rest contain a single quote (e.g. "O'Brien"). You'll end up with a javascript syntax error.

Comment: I know nothing about coding. How do I fix that? Sorry for the lack of understanding.

Comment: you must close that string Marc wrote at the beginning of his comment